# metro style app asynchronous socket issue (send function call before connected)

Tags: sockets, windows-8, microsoft-metro, asyncsocket

i have created a **metro style** datagram server and a client using **Windows.Networking.Sockets**. i am doing code in **c++**

Than i tried to connect and send data from client to server.

but the problem i am facing is that,
as windows metro application is totally **asynchronous**,my app **starts to send data before connection being completed**.

i want an approach through which my send function will send data after the connection completed.

**msdn** has provided a sample code for client server but they use a **button to send data which takes time** to operate meanwhile the connection is completed.Thats why the application runs well.

but i am trying to do client server communication  in the main code without using  send Button.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here b/c you didn't provide any code, but you should use the continuation of your [DatagramSocket.ConnectAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701226.aspx) create_task.  If you put the send data in the task::then, you will not have a problem with the async nature of the call.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780559.aspx) on dealing with async in C++ Windows 8 apps.  Lots of [great examples here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Asynchronous-08009a0d) as well.